# Scilab - Find Butterworth coefficients and filter analog data

Tags: signal-processing, scilab, butterworth

For a project with an accelerometer, I am searching a way to filter some high frequencies.
I am not a signal specialist, but I read that usually for my needs, Butterworth filter is used.

I use Scilab for that purpose, and I am fighting with the interpretation of my results : I have written the following code (at bottom) and compared Scilab output functions to implement this [filtering equation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/5/5/7550fd7e8b5e1aa43d587ff986ef5238.png) in an Arduino :

My questions are :

- what is the difference between cnum function and filter function ?
- the result coefficient of analpf(butt) or zpbutt are

> "coefficients : Num / Den : "
> 1.
>
> 1. 0.063662   0.0020264   0.0000323

where I am expecting a result as [canonical form](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/e/a/cea9aeb4bbf5f4312211e65473147c11.png)
with expected value of

> b1 0.331785003 ; b2 0.99535501 ; b3 0.99535501 ; b4 0.331785003
> a1 -0.965826145 ; a2 -0.582614466 ; a3 -0.106171201

*calculated from external sofware here ([link](https://www.meme.net.au/butterworth.html)) with N=3, low pass, Fc=5, Fs=15.*

Can you look at my code and give me some advice to correct it and have correct coefficients ai and bi ?

```
/////////////////// cleanup
clear;
//clc;
close;


////////////////////// variable declaration
fcut = 5; //cut off frequency hz (delta 1)
fsampl = 15 ; //sampling frequency hz (delta 2)
delta1_in_dB = -3; // attenuation value at fcut
delta2_in_dB = -21; // final attenuation
delta1 = 10^(delta1_in_dB/20)
delta2 = 10^(delta2_in_dB/20)
epsilon = 0; //ripple value [0 1]
rp = [epsilon epsilon] // ripple vector for analpf 

// conversion of attenuation
delta1 = 10^(delta1_in_dB/20);
delta2 = 10^(delta2_in_dB/20);

// N computation
N = log10((1/(delta2^2))-1)/(2*log10(fspan/fcut));
N = ceil(N);
disp("Order",N);

/////////////////// compute different functions to compaire Butterworth
[poleZP,gainZP]=zpbutt(N,fcut*2*%pi);

[hsAna,poleAna,zeroAna,gainAna]=analpf(N,'butt',rp,fcut*2*%pi);

//disp("Pole : Zpbutt ",poleZP , "Analpf ",poleAna)
//disp("Gain : Zpbutt ",gainZP , "Analpf ",gainAna)
//disp("function :",hsAna)
//       conclusion : zpbutt et analpf donnent la même sortie

/////////////////// paramters in linear system
// Generate the equivalent linear system of the filter
num   = gainAna * real(poly(zeroAna,'s'));
den   = real(poly(poleAna,'s'));
elatf = syslin('c',num,den);

Cnum=coeff(num);
Cden=coeff(den)/Cnum;
Cnum=1;

disp('coefficients : Num / Den : ',Cnum,Cden)





/////////////////// plot an exemple to compare csim and filter
rand('normal');
Input = rand(1,1000); // Produce a random gaussian noise
t     = 1:1000;
t     = t*0.01; // Convert sample index into time steps

y_csim = csim(Input,t,elatf); // Filter the signal with csim
y_res = filter(Cnum, Cden, Input) // Filter the signal with filter


// plot curves
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t,Input);
xtitle('The gaussian noise','t','y');
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t,y_csim,'b');
xtitle('The ''csim'' filtered gaussian noise','t','y');
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t,y_res,'r');
xtitle('The ''filter'' filtered gaussian noise','t','y');
```

Thanks in advance for your support !!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've missed a sign inversion when converting the output from that website to canonical form.

The output from that website is:

```
3.014⋅yi = (1⋅xi + 3⋅xi-1 + 3⋅xi-2 + 1⋅xi-3) + -2.911⋅yi-1 + -1.756⋅yi-2 + -0.320⋅yi-3
```

When I convert that to canonical form, I get:

```
yi   (0.331785 + 0.995355*z^-1 + 0.995355*z^-2 + 0.331785*z^-3)
-- = -----------------------------------------------------------
xi      (1 + 0.96582*z^-1 + 0.582614*z^-2 + 0.10617*z^-3)
```

Which means:

```
[b0..b3] = [0.331785   0.99535501 0.99535501 0.331785  ]
[1 a1..a3] = [1.         0.96582614 0.58261447 0.1061712 ]
```

An easy way to get the same answer in scilab is to use their [iir](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/iir.html) filter design function, which does both the analog design and bilinear transformation in one step, like so:

```
--> hz=iir(N,'lp','butt',5./15.,[0 0])
 hz  = 

                                                    
   0.3318051 +0.9954154z +0.9954154z² +0.3318051z³  
   -----------------------------------------------  
       0.1060171 +0.5826442z +0.9657797z² +z³
```

You might say the coefficients look backwards, but be sure to notice the sign of the powers of z; the whole equation has been multiplied by z³/z³, relative to the canonical form you wish to have.  The easy way to deal with this is just to grab the coefficients and [flip them from left to right](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/m2sci_fliplr.html).

```
--> coeff(hz.num)(:,$:-1:1)
 ans  =

   0.3318051   0.9954154   0.9954154   0.3318051

--> coeff(hz.den)(:,$:-1:1)
 ans  =

   1.   0.9657797   0.5826442   0.1060171
```

Comment: Thanks Mark H !
I had also found out this function and with a lot of trials-errors tests, discovered your solution. However, mine is a lot less neat than yours !
I complete my question on next message with my updated code and remarks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my updated code with proposed solution from @Mark H (thanks again !).
I still have some question mark, mainly Scilab oriented, if some one can teach me (but it is not a blocking point for my project).

What are differencies between `flts` and `filter` function ?
My output results are different with those function.

Code :

```
////////////////////// cleanup
clear;
//clc; clear console
close;

////////////////////// variable declaration
fcut = 10000; //cut off frequency hz (delta 1)
fsampl = 100000 ; //sampling frequency hz (delta 2)
delta1_in_dB = -3; // attenuation value at fcut
delta2_in_dB = -21; // final attenuation

// conversion of attenuation
delta1 = 10^(delta1_in_dB/20);
delta2 = 10^(delta2_in_dB/20);

// order N computation
N = log10((1/(delta2^2))-1)/(2*log10(fsampl/fcut));
N = ceil(N);
disp("Order",N);

///////////////////// computer Butterworth transfer function
hz=iir(N,'lp','butt',fcut/fsampl,[ ]);

///////////////////////////// extract coefficient from transfer function
num   = coeff(hz(2));
den   = -1*coeff(hz(3));
gain = 1/num(1)

// display value and graph
disp('gain',gain)
disp('''b'' coefficients : num xi',num)
disp('''a'' coefficients : den yi',den(N:-1:1))

[hzm,fr]=frmag(hz,256);
f = scf(0)
plot(fr,hzm)


/////////////////// plot an exemple
rand('normal');
Input = rand(1,1000); // Produce a random gaussian noise
t     = 1:1000;
t     = t*0.01; // Convert sample index into time steps

//Change from transfer function to linear system
    sl= tf2ss(hz)

//Filter the signal
    fs=flts(Input,sl);

// plot curves of raw and filtered data
f = scf(1)
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,Input,'b');
xtitle('The gaussian noise','t','y');
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,fs,'r');
xtitle('The filtered gaussian noise','t','y');




///////////////////// export on CSV
filename = fullfile(TMPDIR, "data_test_filter.csv");
separator = ";"
M = [t' Input' fs']; //data matrix
csvWrite(M, filename, separator);

filename = fullfile(TMPDIR, "coeff.csv");
C = [gain num den(N:-1:1)] ;//coeff matrix
csvWrite(C, filename, separator);


disp("DONE !");
```

Comment: https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/State_Space_Realization.html